# Create new column in pandas based on another columns where each cell will be numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to compute the quaternion from euler angles. And then I want to store whole quaternion value in one column. Quaternion is numpy.ndarray.

I find similar questions but in all solutions, the columns stores 1D values.

Here my code :

```
import transforms3d

def computeQuat(p,y,r,syscoord):
    return transforms3d.euler.euler2quat(p, y, r, syscoord)

dataClassic['Quaternion'] = (dataClassic.apply(lambda x: computeQuat(x['Pitch_Init'],\
                                        x['Yaw_Init'],\
                                        x['Roll_Init'], 'rxyz'), axis=1))
```

I obtain the error : Shape of passed values is (362, 4), indices imply (362, 6).

If I change the function computeQuat that it returns one value, it works fine :

```
def computeQuat(p,y,r,syscoord):
    return transforms3d.euler.euler2quat(p, y, r, syscoord)[0]
```

But I want to store whole quaternion in one column as numpy.ndarray. Thanks for your help.

I use python 2.

Some lines from my dataframe :

```
Pitch_Init  Yaw_Init  Roll_Init        X        Y        Z
0       0.00000  0.000000   0.000000  0.00000  0.00000   0.0000
1      -3.02664 -0.196047   0.027153  1.15756 -3.73556  60.8734
2      -3.04845 -0.180832   0.024738  1.16244 -3.75089  60.9885
3      -3.06983 -0.168351   0.022593  1.16580 -3.76106  61.0987
4      -3.12110 -0.135368   0.021681  1.18352 -3.78380  61.4627
5       3.11304 -0.130364   0.019365  1.17835 -3.77255  61.5189
6       3.09046 -0.137977   0.017496  1.17643 -3.76929  61.4626
7       3.08333 -0.132229   0.017267  1.17355 -3.76809  61.4604
8       3.07844 -0.141410   0.017119  1.17351 -3.76710  61.4747
9       3.09239 -0.106203   0.018702  1.19171 -3.77195  61.5361
10      3.08501 -0.125604   0.017750  1.19317 -3.76052  61.4881
```

Answer (score 0):

---

New answer:

```
def computeQuat(row):
    quat = (row['Pitch_Init'], row['Yaw_Init'], row['Roll_Init'], 'rxyz')
    return transforms3d.euler.euler2quat(*quat)

df['q0'] = 0
df['q1'] = 0
df['q2'] = 0
df['q3'] = 0

for row_num, row in df.iterrows():
    quat_res = computeQuat(row)
    df.loc[row_num, 'q0'] = quat_res[0]
    df.loc[row_num, 'q1'] = quat_res[1]
    df.loc[row_num, 'q2'] = quat_res[2]
    df.loc[row_num, 'q3'] = quat_res[3]
```

It is not the prettiest solution, but it works.

Comment: I tried your solution, it gives : 
('euler2quat() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)', u'occurred at index 0')

Comment: oh, sorry, I am correcting my answer - now it should be correct.

Comment: Now, I get : 
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (362, 4), indices imply (362, 6)

Comment: Should transforms3d.euler.euler2quat(*quat) return single value per row or multiple? If multiple try to return them to new dataframe and concat it to the old one. Tell me if it will work.

Comment: transforms3d.euler.euler2quat returns numpy.ndarray of size 4
I tried : 

dNew = pd.DataFrame() 
dNew['Quaternion'] = dataClassic.apply(computeQuat, axis=1)
And I obtained the same error, it seems that dataClassic.apply does not want to return the column of numpy.ndarray of size 4

Comment: Check out new solution - I've tried it with the sample you gave, using python 3. Tell me if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works but each quaternion coefficient is stored on the separated column. I want to store at one column all 4 coefficients, as numpy.ndarray